# #if directive code parsing in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Im trying to extract the part of code from my CS file using Roslyn and Im suffering the below problem.

**My C# file code:**

```
    class ConditionalCompilationCode
    {
#if Condition2
            int test2=0; 
#endif
#if Condition1
            int test1=0; 
#endif

        public static void Main1(string[] args)
        {
            int test = 0;
#if Condition1
            test = 1;
#else
            test =2;
#endif

#if Condition2
            test =3;
#else
            test = 4;
#endif

        }
#if Condition2
            private void testmethod1()
        {
            test2 = 1;
        }
#endif
#if !Condition2
        private void testmethod2()
        {
            test1 = 1;
        }
#endif
#if Condition1
        private void testmethod3()
        {
            test1 = 1;
        }
#endif
#if !Condition1
            private void testmethod4()
        {
            test2 = 1;
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

**My roslyn code:**

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(fileContent);

var syntaxRootNode = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
            if (syntaxRootNode.GetFirstToken().Kind() == SyntaxKind.None)
                return;
            foreach (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceSyntax in syntaxRootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().ToArray())
            {

                IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> nodeList = namespaceSyntax.ChildNodes();
                string className = null;
                foreach (SyntaxNode syntaxNode in nodeList)
                {
                    SyntaxKind kind = syntaxNode.Kind();
                    switch (kind)
                    {
                        case SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration:
                            UpdateClassSignature(syntaxNode as TypeDeclarationSyntax);                            
                            break;
                        case SyntaxKind.EnumDeclaration:

                            break;
                        case SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration:

                            break;
                        case SyntaxKind.StructDeclaration:

                            break;

                    }

                }

            }

    private void UpdateClassSignature(TypeDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax)
        {

            foreach (MemberDeclarationSyntax member in classDeclarationSyntax.Members)
            {
                SyntaxKind kind = member.Kind();
                switch (kind)
                {
                    case SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration:
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration:
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration:
                    case SyntaxKind.ConstructorDeclaration:
                    case SyntaxKind.DestructorDeclaration:
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.IndexerDeclaration:
                        ExtractIndexer(member as IndexerDeclarationSyntax, classSign);
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.DelegateDeclaration:
                        //TODO: Add Delegate Support.
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.OperatorDeclaration:
                    case SyntaxKind.ConversionOperatorDeclaration:
                        //Skip.
                        //TODO: Need to add operator suport.
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.EventFieldDeclaration:
                        //TODO: Add support to event.
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.EventDeclaration:
                        //TODO: Add support to event.
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.EnumDeclaration:
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration:
                        break;
                    case SyntaxKind.StructDeclaration:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

While processing the above CS file using roslyn, in the classDeclarationSyntax.Members contains the following three values:

1. MethodDeclarationSyntax MethodDeclaration

   ```
   public static void Main1(string[] args)
   {
       int test = 0;
       #if Condition1
       test = 1;
       #else
       test =2;
       #endif

      #if Condition2
       test =3;
      #else
       test = 4;
     #endif

   }
   ```
2. MethodDeclarationSyntax MethodDeclaration

   ```
   private void testmethod2()
   {
       test1 = 1;
   }
   ```
3. MethodDeclarationSyntax MethodDeclaration

   ```
   private void testmethod4()
   {
       test2 = 1;
   }
   ```

My project has "Condition1" directive alone. Can you help me to get the codes only when the condition has "Condition1" alone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Do you want to filter out a conditional branch or so?

Comment: @Ties I just want to parse my CS file and process the active codes in the parsed syntax tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a `CSharpParseOptions` that calls `WithPreprocessorSymbols()` to pass the symbols you want to define to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. Please refer the code below:
List<string> preProcessorSymbols = new List<string>();
            preProcessorSymbols.Add("Condition1");
            CSharpParseOptions options = CSharpParseOptions.Default;// new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.CSharp6, DocumentationMode.Parse, SourceCodeKind.Regular, preProcessorSymbols);
            options = options.WithPreprocessorSymbols(preProcessorSymbols);
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(fileContent, options);'